# TypeError: common_1.ValidationPipe is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, npm

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema com o ValidationPipe() na hora de rodar a API. Segue meu código a seguir:

```
import {ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common';
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Lama-test API')
  .setDescription('Making an APIREST for Lama')
  .setVersion('1.0')
  .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Recebo a seguinte resposta:
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
^
TypeError: common_1.ValidationPipe is not a constructor
at bootstrap (C:\Users\clemi\Desktop\lama-test\src\main.ts:15:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está aqui `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());` pois como a mensagem de erro diz `ValidaPipe` não é um construtor.

Comment: @Guto certo, também acredito nisso. Mas não sei como corrigir, e parece que esse erro não é comum, pois não encontro nada na internet referente a isso